# Read a binary file stored in HDFS with Python

Tags: python, hdfs, binaryfiles, python-cryptography

I have some binary files.
When i store them to local files i can read them as binary files.

```python
with open("binary_file", 'rb') as f:
    print("Binary file:  ", f.read())
```

Result:

```python
Binary file:   b'Ix\x9d\xdf\xd2\xf6\x83\xe8B\x95.... (a long binary)
```

But i want to store them and retrieve them from HDFS. When i use the following commands:

```python
f = os.popen("hdfs dfs -cat binary_file")
print("Binary file:  ", f.read())
```

I get an error on the 'print':

```python
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2: invalid start byte
```

I think that this commands reads the file as a text file. How can i explicitly read the file as binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.popen()` defaults to a text `r` mode.

Use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead; it defaults to binary:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("hdfs dfs -cat encrypted_file", shell=True)
```